# What dictionary is used on MSE?

Tags: discussion

When I type here what dictionary does the spell checking for me? My local browser dictionary or is it MSE dictionary?

I was using Chrome while typing in the question box. The word `differentiable` was flagged as having wrong spelling. When I typed the same in the search box of Chrome no spelling error was indicated. So I suppose two different spelling dictionaries are used.

That might suggest uses for a dictionary of mathematical words which are not in basic dictionaries.

Comment: In the interest of teaching you how to fish: try typing some nonsense in a text box, right-click on whatever is underlined in red, and note the entries in the popup.

Comment: As far as I can tell, MSE doesn't have dictionary or spell checking functionality. Whatever you have is something provided by your browser.

Comment: I was surprised to see `differentiable` flagged in my Chrome when I type it here but not when I type in the search box of browser. I guess I still don't know how to fish! Then I thought perhaps there can be an additional mini-dictionary of mathematics terms to add to the local dictionary.

Comment: I don't believe Chrome (or most other browsers I've used) does spell-checking in search boxes. You can type any amount of nonsense in there, and you'll not see the red squiggly line at all.

Comment: @Ｊ.M. We must be talking about different boxes. Mine does plenty of red squiggly when I type a word with the wrong spelling. On my page there is Google logo on the left,  a search box with a microphone picture in it, and a magnifier outside of it.

Comment: Hmm, the checker must have been enabled in yours; it's disabled in mine by default.